# Jsoup: "Select only links with text() equal to"

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

One way to cul links with text() that equals some predefined strings is straightforward:

```
Elements links = document.getElementsByTag("a");               
for (Element link : links) {
    if (link.text().equals("So & so") || link.text().equals("such & such") {
        // add link.attr("href") to our container;
    }
}
```

But as the number of text() conditions grows, this approach looks less and less efficient.

Is there a better way to accomplish this in Jsoup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing specific to do with Jsoup, but why not use a Set such as a HashSet to hold your valid Strings?  Then if the set were called "validTextSet", you could quite simply and efficiently test if the text is in the set with

```
     if (validTextSet.contains(link.text())) {
        // add link.attr("href") to our container;
     }
```

Comment: That's definitely a performance improvement and it seems that there isn't a mechanism like this already built into Jsoup so I will be accepting shortly. Interestingly, despite all the great advances in higher-level programming languages, the old 'C' technique of implementing a non-integer switch/case via an array of pointers to functions, still holds true in Java (in disguise). +1 from me, too.

Comment: @ef2011: I'm not surprised that this isn't in Jsoup as it really is not part of parsing the HTML but rather what you do with the information once you get it. Also, I think a HashMap is theoretically quicker than switch/case, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. An **optimized** switch/case in 'C' is really a HashMap in disguise (the hash is used as an instant-access index to an array).